# langchain Root module no longer supported?

Tags: import, openai-api, langchain

How could I fix this:
UserWarning: Importing OpenAI from langchain root module is no longer supported.
UserWarning: Importing LLMChain from langchain root module is no longer supported.
UserWarning: Importing PromptTemplate from langchain root module is no longer supported.

```
from langchain import OpenAI, LLMChain, PromptTemplate
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferWindowMemory
```

tried to directly install OpenAI but didn't recognize it as a package

Answer (score 18):

you can try as below

```
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate 
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferWindowMemory
```

Comment: that worked however I'm now getting an error when I import telebot. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling but it doesn't work.:     import telebot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'

Comment: this is the code:  import telebot

Comment: make sure you are properly installing telebot and adding required API keys https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/

Comment: With langchain 0.1.0 I get the warning that "from langchain.llms import OpenAI" is deprecated with 0.2.0 and the solution is to import it via "from langchain_community.llms import OpenAI"

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the 0.0.339 langchain version and the 1.3.4 openai version. I can import the library like this.

```
from langchain.llms.openai import OpenAI
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferWindowMemory
```

You can aslo import the lib like the other answer. I saw the way that you import libraries on Youtube, but I true if you use the older version langchain and openai, but for the newer version, there are some different in how to import the libraries.

For the question about telebot, in my opinion, there are 2 ways can handle your issues.

Way 1:

`pip install telebot`

After you run this script, you can check in terminal like this.

`pip show telebot`

[image]

Way 2:

You can also install the other library named pyTelegramBotAPI, link to instruction is https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/tree/master.

`pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`

After you run this script, you can import telebot.
[image]

Here is my solutions. I'm using python 3.11 version. Hope to useful for you.